# Stop absolute positioned element from overlapping left column CSS

Tags: css, css-position, absolute, fluid-layout

I am using position absolute to overlay a transparent image, but I want to center the images in their containing div and not overlap the neighboring sidebar when the browser is resized. I've done a lot of searching with no luck. Position relative on the parent div doesn't seem to work.

Here's the jsfiddle and code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lp7kxot4/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="columnA">
    </div><!-- #columnA -->
    <div id="columnB">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>HEADER</h1>
        </div><!-- #header -->
        <div id="content">
            <img class="posAbs" src="http://i6.minus.com/jxIcIq7rF6ix4.jpg" />
            <span id="imageOverlay"><img class="posAbs" src="http://i.minus.com/ipkPzdUV85vpR.gif" /></span>
        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #columnB -->
</div><!-- #wrap -->
```

CSS:

```
/* GLOBAL */
html,body,#wrap{height:100%;}
body{font-size: 62.5%;}

/* STRUCTURE */
#columnA{
    width:18em;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
#columnB{
    min-width:40em;
}
#content{
    position:relative;
}
.posAbs {
    position:absolute;
    left: calc( (100% + 18em) / 2);
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized upping the min-width for #columnB does the trick

```
#columnB{
    min-width:58em;
}
```

Unfortunately, for some reason it does not work on the page I'm working on, must be something else in there causing it to not work the same. I guess I'll have to isolate the problem. Here's the working fix for anyone that's curious:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lp7kxot4/4/